# Are these trees some type of poplar?

Tags: identification, trees

Here are a few pictures of some trees in my yard. I am trying to determine what type they are. I'm fairly certain they are some type of poplar tree. But I am not sure of the specific type. This is in New Hampshire and it is fairly close to some seasonal wet lands.

*click any picture for full size*

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: http://www.oplin.org/tree/ might help you.

Comment: I've added a close up of the leaf. I wasn't able to find any branches that fell off with leaves on them so I tired to zoom in to show the leaf arrangement. Hope that helps. Thanks!

Comment: If it's not a cottonwood, you might want to consider whether it's some kind of an aspen (not a quaking aspen, though, since they have white bark that looks a lot different). Aspen leaves look like that, from the pictures I've seen, and aspens are also in the same genus as poplars. Maybe it is a bigtooth aspen (granted it doesn't have big teeth, but not all the leaves for them I've seen pictures of had big teeth either). There might be other considerations, too.

Comment: @user Aspens typically have much wider serration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe those are young-ish specimens of [*Populus deltoides*, or eastern cottonwood.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Populus_deltoides) So you did guess in the right genus. This is a very common tree in your area of the US, as well as many others. Here's a map of where it is distributed:

[image]

Comment: So this was one of my first guesses but to me it seems the eastern cottonwood is much whiter. This is more gray?

Comment: @David They start out lighter, and as they age the bark becomes darker, and more and more furrowed. Eastern cottonwood is not to be confused with quaking aspen, which has nearly white bark.

Answer (score 0):

They look a lot like the hybrid cottonwood I have in my backyard. Not sure what kind of poplar my eastern cottonwoods are crossed with but they are very tall, about 3' in diameter and they DO cotton every summer.